# Equivalent particular norms, can you point the right direction?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $P([0,1])$ be the space of all the polinomial with complex entries, defined in $[0,1]$ . Show that $||f||_\infty=sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|$ and $||f||_1= \int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt$ are equivalent norms.

Profesor said this would be easy but I've lost half my day thinking on an approach, any hint will be appreciated!, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The notion of equivalent norms that I have is the following: Two norms $||\cdot||_1,||\cdot||_2$ over a vector space $V$ are equivalent if there are constants $C_1,C_2>0$ such that for every $x\in V$, $$C_1||x||_1\leq ||x||_2\leq C_2||x||_1.$$

Is it the same definition that you have? If so, under this definition, we can show the norms $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ and $||f||_1$ are not equivalent.

Suppose they are equivalent, and take $C_1,C_2>0$ such that for every polinomial $f\in P([0,1])$ we have $$C_1||f||_1 \leq ||f||_\infty\leq C_2||f||_1.\hspace{1cm}(*)$$

Take $n$ large enough such that $C_2<n+1$ (that is, $C_2\cdot \frac{1}{n+1}<1$), and consider the polynomial $f=x^n$. Then, we have

$$C_2\cdot ||f||_1=C_2\cdot \int_0^1 |x^n|\,dx=C_2\cdot \dfrac{1}{n+1}<1=||f||_\infty,$$contradicting the inequality $(*)$.

---

Probably your teacher was thinking about the space of all polynomials with bounded degree, which is a finite-dimensional vector space and it can be proven that for every such space all norms are equivalent. A proof of this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168275/proof-that-every-finite-dimensional-normed-vector-space-is-complete), although I believe any book of functional analysis (and several of linear algebra) will also contain a proof of it.