# $P_n$ is not a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $P_n$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$, with $n$ an integer. Now consider the norm $||x||=\max_i|a_i|$. Show tha $P_n$ is not a Banach space.

I'm learning functional analysis (from Kesavan's book) and I'm struggling with this argument. I know, by the Baire's theorem, that is a set is of first category, that is, a countable union of nowhere dense sets, then it cannot be a Banach space. The thing is, how can I prove the space $P_n$ is nowhere dense? I have no experience working with nowhere dense subsets. Is there any equivalent result to conclude $P_n$ is a countable union of nowhere dense vector spaces?

Comment: Are you sure you want the degree to be at most a fixed $n$? That space looks remarkably similar to $(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, \| \cdot \|_\infty)$, which *is* a Banach space

Comment: Not just similar but isometric to....

Comment: It is a Banach space. Fun exercise: Prove that every finite-dimensional normed space is a Banach space. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168275/proof-that-every-finite-dimensional-normed-vector-space-is-complete

Comment: I strongly suspect the exercise actually asks (or was intended to ask) about the vector space of **all** polynomials, not just those of degree $\le n$.

Comment: Each $P_n$ is closed in $C[0,1]$ with empty interior. Every proprer subspace has empty interior.